# Can not query geo_point using geo polygon filter

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, polygon, geo, geopoints

Hi I'm trying to query geo_point in ElasticSearch, using the query syntax **[geo polygon filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-polygon-filter.html)** in the official document], but no reusult is returned. 
[image: geo pologon filter no result]

Here are some details:
I use [river plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) to index the data from MySQL into ES with the definition of mapping (a nested structure but coordinate.value is geo_point).

[image: geo_point mapping definition]

I can see the documents from head plugin:

[image: ElasticSearch document]

The query json is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_polygon": {
          "coordinate.value": {
            "points": [
              [
                -180,
                90
              ],
              [
                -180,
                -90
              ],
              [
                180,
                -90
              ],
              [
                -180,
                90
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's the correct query method to get geo_point? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

polygon should be closed (ie first and last points should be the same).

Comment: You sir are the absolute hero! Just to make a short extension on this.

If you are getting the coordinates from google maps for example, be sure to have the coordinates in order. For example (nw, ne, se, sw, nw).

ElasticSearch is innacurate if not